# Jenkins Dependency error with ruby-runtime while installing Cucumber plugin blocks execution of cucumber tests

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber

**Environment**: Live
**System**: Windows 7 & Windows 10 - 64 bit
**Browser**: IE & Chrome
**Version**: Jenkins: 2.60.1 ; Cucumber Plugin: v0.0.2 ; ruby-runtime Plugin: v0.12

**Test Steps**:

- Install the latest version of Jenkins
- Install all the suggested
  plugins by Jenkins
- Once Jenkins is ready navigate to Manage Jenkins
  -> Manage Plugins -> click on available plugins -> Search for cucumber plugin
- Install Cucumber plugin which comes along with the
  ruby-runtime dependency
- Restart Jenkins after download is complete

**Expected Behavior**: Cucumber plugin is installed successfully along with the ruby-runtime dependency

**Actual Behavior**: We get an error on Jenkins saying - *There are dependency errors loading some plugins: Cucumber Plugin v0.0.2 ◦ruby-runtime v0.10 is missing*. To fix, install v0.10 or later.

We have tried installing both the plugins through plugins manager & also through manual upload multiple times but we still get the dependency error. When we check in the Jenkins plugins folder on windows then we can see both the plugins there but it is somehow not shown in the installed plugins section on the plugin manager. This is blocking us from running cucumber tests. We have tried re-installing Jenkins & the plugins multiple times but we get the same dependency error.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCK58.jpg)

Comment: Ever figure this out?